# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' error flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone I am coding chat app but I faced error that say

" type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String? "

and I tried to solve this but I know where is the error came

when I run this code:

" ControllerModel searchedUser = ControllerModel.fromMap(userMap); "

after stream builder.

please if there any solution help and thank you so much. [Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xjwk.png),
[Emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Rj2.png), [userMap data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S7oA.png)

this is my code:

```
// Search users class

import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:chat_app/getX%20files/models/chat_room_model.dart';
import 'package:chat_app/getX%20files/view/chatting_files/chat_room.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../../../main.dart';
import '../../controller.dart';
import '../../models/model.dart';

class AddAndSearchUsers extends SearchDelegate<String?> {

  final ControllerModel userModel = Get.find();
  final FirebaseFirestore _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<ChatRoomModel?> getChatroomModel(ControllerModel targetUser) async {
    ChatRoomModel? chatRoom;

    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _fireStore
        .collection("chatRooms")
        .where("participants.${userModel.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
        .where("participants.${targetUser.uid}", isEqualTo: true)
        .get();

    if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      // Fetch the existing one
      var docData = snapshot.docs[0].data();
      ChatRoomModel existingChatroom =
          ChatRoomModel.fromMap(docData as Map<String, dynamic>);

      chatRoom = existingChatroom;
    } else {
      // Create a new one
      ChatRoomModel newChatroom = ChatRoomModel(
        chatRoomId: uuid.v1(),
        lastMessage: "",
        participants: {
          userModel.uid.toString(): true,
          targetUser.uid.toString(): true,
        },
      );

      await _fireStore
          .collection("chatRooms")
          .doc(newChatroom.chatRoomId)
          .set(newChatroom.toMap());

      chatRoom = newChatroom;

      log("New Chatroom Created!");
    }

    return chatRoom;
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(onPressed: () => query = '', icon: const Icon(Icons.clear)),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () => Get.back(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: GetBuilder<Controller>(
          init: Controller(),
          builder: (_) {
            return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _fireStore.collection("users").where("email", isEqualTo: query)
                    .where("email", isNotEqualTo: userModel.email)
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      QuerySnapshot dataSnapShot = snapshot.data as QuerySnapshot;
                      if (dataSnapShot.docs.isNotEmpty) {

                        Map<String, dynamic> userMap =
                        dataSnapShot.docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

/// ERROR HERE ------->
                        ControllerModel searchedUser = ControllerModel.fromMap(userMap);

                        return ListView(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white38,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      ChatRoomModel? chatRoomModel = await 
                                     getChatroomModel(searchedUser);
                                      if (chatRoomModel != null) {
                                         Get.to(() => ChatRoom(
                                            targetUser: searchedUser,
                                            userModel: userModel,
                                            chatRoom: chatRoomModel));
                                      }
                                    },
                                    title: Text(searchedUser.name!),
                                    subtitle: Text(searchedUser.email!),
                                  )),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const Center(child: Text('No result found'));
                      }
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      const Text('Error');
                    }
                  } else {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  //controllerModel.saveSearch = snapshot.data!.docs as Map<String, dynamic>?;
                  return const Text('No result found');
                });
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(child: Text('Find people'));
  }
}
```

```
// ControllerModel


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ControllerModel extends GetxController {
  //const ModelClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  String? uid,username,email,name,password,phone;

  ControllerModel({this.uid, this.username, this.name,this.email, this.password, this.phone});

  ControllerModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    uid = map["uid"];
    username = map["username"];
    email = map["email"];
    name = map["name"];
    password = map["password"];
    phone = map["phone"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "uid": uid,
      "username": username,
      "email": email,
      "name": name,
      "password": password,
      "phone": phone
    };
  }


    ... CODE NOT IMPORTANT
}
```

```
//ChatRoomModel

class ChatRoomModel {
  String? chatRoomId;
  Map<String, dynamic>? participants;
  String? lastMessage;

  ChatRoomModel({this.chatRoomId, this.participants, this.lastMessage});

  ChatRoomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    chatRoomId = map["chatRoomId"];
    participants = map["participants"];
    lastMessage = map["lastMessage"];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "chatRoomId": chatRoomId,
      "participants": participants,
      "lastMessage": lastMessage
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: would you mind printing `userMap` before the line that gives you an error, it is quite likely one of the parameters is a list instead of a string

Comment: When I print userMap it's printed data that is comes from dataSnapShot

Comment: Yes I believe some of that data might be a list when you are expecting a  String, the most likely candidate is phone, but I can't tell without looking at the data

Comment: Yes maybe, I uploaded the userMap above would you mind to see it?

Comment: I solve the error finally, the error was from the phone number I forgot to convert it to String thank you very much bro for your notice.

Comment: Glad you solved it!